# Restoring the default settings for Whisker Menu in Ubuntu Studio 16.04

Tags: 16.04

How would I restore default settings in the Whisker Menu?

I have moved some items around and programs in Graphic section disappeared.
I have tried adding items and then decided that I didn't want one. So I told it to delete that item
but item still shows up while using Menu Editor says that item is not there.

How would I remove that item?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your user's home directory for config files.

Ex: "/home/yourusername/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu"

I just had some problem too and fix it by copying the default file and then modify in a text editor the xml file.

Make a backup of your current xfce-applications.menu file, then from a terminal:

(replace yourusername)

```
cp /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntustudio/menus/xfce-applications.menu /home/yourusername/.config/menus/
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Xubuntu 19.10, I could only recover the full menu by keeping a safe copy of /home/$USER/.config/xfce4/panel/whiskermenu-1.rc .  Restoring xfce-applications.menu did not restore my "favorites" list.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Studio 20, just remove (backup first if you wish) the contents of the $HOME/.config/menus/ directory, then restart your session and you'll get the menu items reset to the default.

Also, if you use Ubuntu Studio and don't want to spoil the menus (those having Audio, Video, Graphics tools organized by categories), you should **NEVER** use the `menulibre` application to set any change, use always `alacarte` instead, though the Audio, Video and Graphics sections cannot be neither seen nor modified with `Alacarte` (neither with `menulibre`, but at least `alacarte` does not mess the menus up).

Pressing the right mouse button on the menu icon and then `Edit applications`, opens `alacarte` by default.